# Getting file name and extension from url's without filenames

Tags: php, guzzle, guzzle6

I am looking at downloading a file, for later to upload it again to a API to check if the file is malicious.

At first it was easy, if the filename + extension was in the URL, but seeing that is not always the case, i would not know the exact filename and extension that is presented to me, so when trying to save it to a tempfile, i would not be able to assign a file extension to it.

Is there a possibility to grab this filename in the response somehow? Or at least the extension, so i can add it to my temporary file before uploading it again..

Here is what i currently have ( I am aware that i am currently just using a tmpfilename, but that will change once i know how to check for the file extension):

```
public function download($url, $tmpfilename, $method)
    {
        $client = new Client([
            // Base URI is used with relative requests
            'base_uri' => $url,
            'sink' => $tmpfilename,
        ]);
        try {
            $response = $client->request($method);
            if (is_bool($response)) {
                return $response;
            } else {
                return $response->getBody()->getContents();
            }
        } catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException $e) {
            return false;
        } catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException $e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: A file name extension can be changed easily and doesn't have to match the file content.

Comment: That's fine, the question was really not related to that. I was just wondering how one would access the file and filename that is being downloaded, from a url that does not include the filename in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can guess the file extension using the `Content-Type` response header.

For example, with [ralouphie/mimey](https://github.com/ralouphie/mimey) to do the conversion:

```
$extension = $mimes->getExtension($response->getHeaderLine('Content-Type'));
```

Comment: How would you end up adding the extension before you run the request if i use the code i have above though? Because it will return the `$response->getBody()->getContents()`. I tried to make it download a txt file, so $file = guzzlerequestabove, then `mime_content_type($file)`, but that only returns `application/octet-stream`.

Comment: You need original response, because only it contains the original `Content-Type`.

Comment: BTW, if you use `sink` you probably don't need to `$response->getBody()->getContents()`, because the content is already written into the file.

Comment: I would only want to return the file itself, and not the Guzzle request. If i would not return the body/contents, i would return the whole guzzle request no?

Comment: It really depends on your needs. You can use `sink` to 1) directly write the response body to a file, 2) rename it according to the `Content-Type` and 3) finally return the result file name from your method (for example).